# Medium Frequency Trading - Better labelling strategy?

Tags: neural-networks, python, deep-learning, finance, labeling

> The mid-price at time $t$ is denoted by $$p_t = \frac{s_t^{a,1} +
>  s_t^{b,1}}{2}.$$
>
> This mid-price can evolve in minimum increments of half a tick but is
>   almost always observed to move at increments of a tick over time
>   intervals of a millisecond or less. In our feature set, each limit
>   order book update is recorded as an observation. Each observation is
>   labeled based on whether the mid-price will increase, decrease or
>   remain over a horizon $h$: $$Y_t = \Delta p^t_{t+h},$$ where $\Delta
>  p^t_{t+h}$ is the forecast the discrete mid-price changes from time
>   $t$ to $t+h$, given measurement of the predictors up to time $t$. The
>   forecasting horizon $h$ can be chosen to represent a fixed number of
>   events or can be a fixed time interval.

This definition is from *A High Frequency Trade Execution Model for Supervised Learning* (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.03870.pdf).

I think it is somewhat doubtful that the way Mr. Dixon label data.

> **Strategies (Labelling):**
>
> 1. Matthew Dixon`s way - If the mid-price at time $t$ is denoted by $p_t = \frac{s_t^{a,1} + s_t^{b,1}}{2}$, then each observation is
>      labelled bases on whether the mid-price will increase, decrease or
>      remain over a horizon $h$. So the label $1$ is for the increase, $-1$
>      is for the decreasing and $0$ is if it remains stable.
> 2. My way -  If the mid-price at time $t$ is denoted by $p_t = \frac{s_t^{a,1} + s_t^{b,1}}{2}$, then each observation is labelled
>      bases on the fact that it is a good place to buy, sell or not buy
>      shares. So the label $1$ is for "buying stocks", $-1$ for "selling
>      stocks" and $0$ for "doing nothing"?

I would like to do High Frequency Trading, but I don't think it's the conventional way. Since I am a small trader, and I don't have many a million of dollars to invest, I don't plan to make millions of transactions (reason: broker fees) a day. So I would like the machine to make a reasonable number of transactions per day according to my budget. In other words, I would like the machine to be able to trade at the same frequency that a standard trader would.

What is the best strategy for labeling my data?

Mr. Dixon labels his data in a first way, so his prediction models will only tell him future times if the action will go up, down, or remain stable. So if I label my data in the second way, then his models will indicate the good times when he has to buy, sell or not buy shares.

In your opinion, why the first labelling strategy should be better than the second labelling strategy?

### Update

Visual representing an implementation of the second strategy.

[image]

### UPDATE 2

Here is an implementation of the second strategy :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal

def label(name):
    df = pd.read_csv(name,lineterminator='\n')
    num_iter = len(df.index)
    print(num_iter)
    new_df = df.iloc[[0]]
    step = 50
    for index in range(0,num_iter,step):
        price_mean = df.iloc[list(range(index,index+step))]['Price'].mean()
        row = df.iloc[[index]]
        row['Price'][index] = price_mean
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df,row])
        print(index)
    the_df = new_df.iloc[1:]   
    vector = the_df['Price']
    print(len(vector))
    space = 100
    print('Detect peaks |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||')
    indexes = scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt(vector, np.arange(1, space),
        max_distances=np.arange(1, space)*2)
    indexes = np.array(indexes) - 1
    print('Peaks are: %s' % (indexes))
    indexes = [i * step for i in indexes]
    action_list = []
    sell_index = []
    sell_value = []
    buy_index = []
    buy_value = []
    num = 0
    profit = 4
    for i, row in df.iterrows():

            if(i in indexes):
                price = df.iloc[[i]]["Price"].mean()
                try:
                list_after = list(range(i, i+50000))
                price_after = df.iloc[list_after]["Price"].mean()
                delta = price_after - price 
                if ( delta > profit  ):
                    print(i, delta, 'buy')
                    action_list.append(1)
                    buy_index.append(i)  
                    buy_value.append(price)
                    num = num+1
                elif( delta < -profit ):
                    print(i, delta, 'sell')
                    action_list.append(-1)
                    sell_index.append(i)  
                    sell_value.append(price)
                    num = num+1
                else:
                    print(i, delta)
                    action_list.append(0)
                except:
                action_list.append(0)
                print('no sufficient data')  
            else:

            action_list.append(0)

    del action_list[0]
    action_list.append(0)
    df['label'] = action_list
    print('Transactions : '+str(num)+' |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||')
    df.to_csv('edited_'+name)

label('TnS_DCIX.csv')
```

Essentially, I try to find peaks then assign the label according to the stock price after that with a good space.

Here is a sample of what is inside `TnS_DCIX.csv`:

```
,Unnamed: 0,#=TimeAndSale,EventSymbol,EventTime,Time,Sequence,ExchangeCode,Price,Size,BidPrice,AskPrice,SaleConditions,Flags
0,367,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-30 09:30:00.405,20150331-093000-0400,395:2,Q,2.72,138914,2.76,2.8,@O X,22596
1,368,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-30 09:30:00.405,20150331-093000-0400,395:3,Q,2.71,138914,2.76,2.8,@  Q,8256
2,391,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-30 09:30:01.000,20150331-093000-0400,990:4,D,2.73,300,2.75,2.76,@4  ,22592
3,399,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-30 09:30:02.115,20150331-093002-0400,105:5,D,2.43,200,2.75,2.76,@4  ,22592
4,401,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-30 09:30:02.201,20150331-093002-0400,192:6,D,2.23,2,2.75,2.76,@4 I,22592
5,404,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-30 09:30:02.660,20150331-093002-0400,649:7,Q,2.54,4,2.75,2.76,@  I,8256
6,422,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-30 09:30:04.337,20150331-093004-0400,327:9,D,2.23,287,2.75,2.76,@   ,8260
7,433,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-30 09:30:06.814,20150331-093006-0400,803:10,D,2.23,17,2.75,2.76,@  I,8256
8,437,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-30 09:30:07.922,20150331-093007-0400,912:12,Q,2.742,100,2.75,2.76,@F  ,22596
9,444,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-30 09:30:09.081,20150331-093009-0400,71:13,D,2.731,3,2.75,2.76,@  I,8256
10,445,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-31 09:30:09.468,20150331-093009-0400,458:15,Q,2.72,100,2.75,2.76,@F  ,22596
11,448,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-31 09:30:15.828,20150331-093015-0400,818:16,D,2.72,5,2.75,2.76,@4ZI,22592
12,450,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-31 09:30:15.855,20150331-093015-0400,845:17,D,2.71,100,2.75,2.76,@4Z ,22592
13,451,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-31 09:30:15.858,20150331-093015-0400,848:18,D,2.75,66,2.75,2.76,@4ZI,22592
14,452,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-31 09:30:15.858,20150331-093015-0400,848:19,D,2.714,8,2.75,2.76,@4ZI,22592
15,453,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-31 09:30:15.858,20150331-093015-0400,848:20,D,2.732,2,2.75,2.76,@4ZI,22592
16,454,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-31 09:30:15.858,20150331-093015-0400,848:21,D,2.732,2,2.75,2.76,@4ZI,22592
17,455,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-31 09:30:15.858,20150331-093015-0400,848:22,D,2.714,10,2.75,2.76,@4ZI,22592
18,459,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-31 09:30:20.840,20150331-093020-0400,830:23,D,2.742,40,2.75,2.76,@  I,8256
19,460,TimeAndSale,ZNGA,2015-03-31 09:30:21.659,20
```

Comment: Is it a bad question? What is wrong with that question?

Comment: I am the one who first down-voted your question  (I don't know about the second down-vote). The reason why I downvoted it was that I found your post factually wrong. HTF approach *but* without millions of transactions. A hugely competitive and extensively researched field *but* with the main modelling vehicle being an HTF reference that hopefully (?) translates to a long-term trading strategy (effectively ignoring most of current Quant. Finance literature). Being straight-forward with you: this does not seem like a well-researched or useful question right now.

Comment: I do not aim to appear unreasonably harsh or demotivational. I want you though to appreciate the difficulty of what you want to do as well as the necessary work needed to make a reasonable question on a hard matter. (Also you might want to visit the dedicated [Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange website)

Comment: I appreciate the courage and honesty of your answer. I think I have the capacity to lead such a project with a successful experience in mathematics and programming. I'm just trying to come up with the best strategy for tagging my data, but they're downgrading me instead of advising me. Are you able to advise me on a good strategy to establish in the context of my question?

Comment: (+1) This may appear to be a "beginner" question, but it is well thought out and constructed. There is a good statistical question here regarding how to select an appropriate response variable for a supervised model. I think it might be improved by (a) clarifying under the "Strategies" box how exactly you are assigning the label in method #2 (rather than have to dive into the [straightforward] python code to figure that out) and (b) why might strategy #1 have been selected from a *statistical* standpoint...

Comment: Often, when modeling, we want to try to maximize our effective sample size even in the presence of (auto)correlated data while trading off other practical modeling constraints/considerations. You might start off by comparing strategies #1 and #2 in this regard...

Comment: Separately, sometimes the *interpretation* of technical jargon can vary even within a field depending on who you are speaking with (@usεr11852), so I would urge respondents not too focus too sharply on this facet of the question. What precisely is meant by "HFT" can vary even amongst (very) sophisticated practitioners. That said, as in any field, it is valuable to immerse oneself in the existing literature; in any empirical field many very smart people have thought very hard about the problems and it pays to assimilate their experience as quickly and completely as practicable.

Comment: @cardinal The function try to find peaks then assign the label according to the stock price after that with a good space.

Comment: I reverted my downvote.